# Create Input box with Submit Button Redirect to site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want help in creating a Input box with only a submit button which redirect user to another site.

when user typed a url in the input box and clicked submit button

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: ***I want help*** sure, can you show us were you are stuck..

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
      function myFunction() {
        window.location.href="http://programminghead.com";
      }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First make an input box and a Button in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="link"><br/>
<button onclick="redirectFunction()">Redirect me!</button>
```

Then in your javascript file

```
function redirectFunction(){
    const link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Remember to put the `<script>` tag into the body of the html file